# How to make wait MediaPlayer for other hit requests?

Tags: java, android

There is a play button(sound review), when I hit it plays, but when I hit several times, it plays multiply.
I wanted to stop this with other topic's codes, didn't help, any idea?

```
img_scream1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
                if(mediaControl.isPlaying()==true){
                    mediaControl.pause();
                }
            else
                {
                    mediaControl = MediaPlayer.create(java_sounds_scary.this, R.raw.hooray);
                    mediaControl.start();
                }


        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to something like this:

```
boolean isPaused = true;

img_scream1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View view) {
           if(isPaused){
            mediaControl = MediaPlayer.create(java_sounds_scary.this, R.raw.hooray);
            mediaControl.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                mp.reset();
            }
        });
                    mediaControl.start();
                    isPaused = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    mediaControl.pause();
                    isPaused = true;
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: It worked in half.
When user hit play button, will wait to end. If user hit that button again, will have to wait to end. I mean setOnCompleteListener is also needed I think.

Comment: I cannot help any further when I don't know what you have done in your codes, And I don't think `setOnCompletionListener` will solve your current issue. BTW I updated my answer with `OnCompletionListener`.

Answer (score 0):

Don't create the `mediaControl` instance every time(**Which makes the song to load from begining**). Instead, you can initialise `mediaControl` to `null` and create an instance of it when it is `null`

```
    mediaControl =null;
    img_scream1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
            public void onClick (View view){
                if (mediaControl == null) {
                    mediaControl = MediaPlayer.create(java_sounds_scary.this, R.raw.hooray);
                }
                if (mediaControl.isPlaying() == true) {
                    mediaControl.pause();
                } else {
                    mediaControl.start();
                }
        }
    });
```